# Does this cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, boost-foreach

Address sanitizer is complaining.

```
struct X
{
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
};

X foo();

const X& bar(const X& x)
{
  return x;
}

BOOST_FOREACH(const auto& xitem, bar(foo()))
{
  //use xitem
}
```

Comment: _"Address sanitizer is complaining"_ - What exactly is it complaining _about_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The FOREACH is happening on a reference to a struct which has been created by the foo call, and gone out of scope after being passed through to bar()

Comment: Are you sure? Boost documentation says, it works with temporary.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/foreach.html#foreach.introduction.examples

Comment: Where do you see that in the linked text?

Comment: Iterate over an expression that returns a sequence by value (i.e. an rvalue):

Comment: Exactly - "returns a sequence by value", not returns a sequence by reference

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this causes undefined behavior.

When you bind a const reference to a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the scope of the bound reference. In your case, this is the function `bar`. Thus, you cannot access the temporary after the `bar` function exits.

**Edit:**

Looked it up in the standard and actually the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the full expression containing `bar`. So it depends on how `BOOST_FOREACH` is implemented whether your code is UB or not.

From N3337 12.2.5

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a
>   function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full
>   expression containing the call.

Comment: But, wont the temporary be caught in another reference? Thus extending the lifetime till that reference?

Comment: @balki AFAIK there is no such thing as rebinding a temporary.